# How does Firebase Test Lab benefit a developer?

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want to use the firebase test lab for an app testing. I was comparing the spark plan and flame plan but there aren't any different. I would like to know what the blaze plan will offer. 
When I test with the spark or flame plan, it doesn't allow me to do the implementation testing. The results I receive from a robo test is not that accurate. Can someone please help me understand the test lab?

Answer (score 1):

The Blaze plan give you unlimited testing, but you have to pay per minute of test time.  It doesn't increase the quality of a Robo test, unless you need more time for it to complete.  Typically, with Blaze, you write your own Espresso tests to test specific use cases in your app.

Comment: Thank you. How does the test lab benefit a developer?

Comment: It gives you a way to test your app on multiple devices before you ship it to your customers.

Comment: Is that the only benefit it can give a developer?

Comment: You should read the documentation to get a full understanding of the product.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/

Comment: I did read the website many times, but the website didn't mention anything about the benefits of using the test lab or how it is useful. It just mentions how it works.

Comment: Software testing is a pretty well understood activity.  It prevents errors from reaching your users and improves the stability of your software.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing